# How do i auto scroll to bottom of a listview on pageshow in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, cordova

The only thing i have inside the "content" of my page is a listview. On `pageshow` I would like it to automatically be scrolled to the bottom of the list. How do i achieve this. I do not know how many `li`'s are their in my list if that matters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retrieve `.offset().top` of *listview* `:last-child`.

1. **Solution one:**

   Using `.animate()` with `scrollTop` option.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
     var last_li = $("ul li:last-child").offset().top;
     $("body").animate({
       scrollTop: last_li
     }, 1000); /* increase / decrease animation speed */
   });
   ```

   > **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/v83Ep/)**
2. **Solution two:**

   Using [`$.mobile.silentScroll()`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.silentScroll/) special function.

   ```
   $(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
     var last_li = $("ul li:last-child").offset().top;
     setTimeout(function () {
       $.mobile.silentScroll(last_li);
     }, 50); /* increase / decrease delay */
   });
   ```

   > [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LqR6Q/)

---

> **Note** that [`pageshow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pageshow/) event is deprecated as of jQM 1.4 and will be removed in jQM 1.5. Its' replacement is [`pagecontainershow`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/#event-show).

Comment: i appreciate your answer. Is there a tweak to this soln where i can make the page appear at the bottom of the list rather than it visibly scrolling down which i assume happens with animate.

Comment: @vijar you can use `$.mobile.silentScroll()` but you need to `setTimeout()` as in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/LqR6Q/ because `.offset()` cant be retrieved before the page is created.

Comment: @vijar i've updated my answer with two solutions, pick whichever suits you and play with _delay_ values.

Comment: Do you know a soln to achieve the same but for a tradition ul not a jqm listview ? . Still using jqm but the list is just normal not al listview

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46178/discussion-between-omar-and-vijar)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).scrollTop($('.content li:last-child').position().top)
```

Comment: CAn you provide an example in a fiddle. i am not able to get this to work . Thanks